# Infinity loop - Axios Interceptor Refresh token in React app

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios interceptor for refresh token when the access token is expired. Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import dayjs from 'dayjs'


const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'


let authTokens = localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers:{Authorization: `Bearer ${authTokens?.access}`}
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async req => {
    if(!authTokens){
        authTokens = localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authTokens?.access}`
    }

    const user = jwt_decode(authTokens.access)
    const isExpired = dayjs.unix(user.exp).diff(dayjs()) < 1;

    if(!isExpired) return req

    const response = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/api/token/refresh/`, {
        refresh: authTokens.refresh
      });

    localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(response.data))
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`
    return req
})


export default axiosInstance;
```

But I got a problem when calling multiple requests, it goes to an infinite loop. Anyone can help me to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setInterval(() => { your code here })` instead :D

you may see some tutorials like w3schools, etc they always add 0 in the end like : `setInterval(() => { do some code }, 0)`
but it’s not needed :D because default is 0 :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean? Where I should use setInterval to fix this? And what is the purpose of doing this? Could you please explain that to me? I'm new to axios interceptor, so... :((

Comment: in pro-coder : performance is a very very important point to pro-coder

performance will let your code better, but if your cpu too high then it will be very very lag

so pro-coder will not always refresh the whole axio instead of umm…

like : i wanna make a thing that updates it position for every frame

then we will just adjust the position, not refreshing the whole axio / game

or else:

Answer (score 0):

I would make the interceptor as response interceptor and not a request interceptor.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
   return response
}, 
function (error) {
   if (error.response.status === 401) {
     ...fetch token and retry
   }
```